# How to get host url in lightswitch application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, appdomain, host, lightswitch-2013

I am developing lightswitch application.

I am opening one MVC view page from DesktopClient to server project and server project is my MVC project.

This code is for open or redirect to view page from DesktopClient.

```
Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
                {
                    dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");

                    shell.ShellExecute("http://localhost:39360/Controller/Index");
                }
                else if (!System.Windows.Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
                {
                    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:39360/Controller/Index"), "_blank");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            });
```

Still working fine because now application in local host. But I don't know after my application host somewhere then what will be the domain or host name. So i want dynamic host name

Can you please suggest what is the best why to get like `www.example.com`. 
and then I will concatenate `/Search/Index`.

You're answer will appreciable:)

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: Did my proposed answer help to provide a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source to determine the host name at runtime.  This object contains a wealth of properties relating to the currently running application e.g.:

```
Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source.Host);
});
```